# When the resultant doesn't act on the same object as the components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, torque

I can understand what the resultant means when it acts on the same object as the components. What I don't understand is situations like this: If two oppositely parallel forces (red arrows in diagram) act at the ends of a beam then according to my textbook the resultant will act in thin air (blue arrow in diagram) outside of the beam. This doesn't make sense to me as it seems to be saying that if I apply two unequal forces to a beam, the beam won't move (because the resultant doesn't act on the beam!)

A thorough explanation of this phenomenon would be highly appreciated!

Diagram:

[image]

Edit: Here is what the book says.

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is situations like this: If two oppositely parallel forces (red arrows in diagram) act at the ends of a beam then according to my textbook the resultant will act in thin air

That is incorrect. A force can't act 'in thin air': it would have no effect on the beam.

In order to find the resultant force and its position, the *net force* and *net torque* of the resultant has to be the same as the individual forces combined:

[image: Resultant]

1. **Net force:** as there are only forces acting in the vertical direction (with 'up' designated as the positive sense), the net resultant force $F_R$ is:

$$\boxed{F_R=F_2-F_1}$$

2. **Net torque:** we can take the torque about the point $O$, so we get:

$$F_R\times x=F_2\times L$$
$$\boxed{x=\frac{F_2L}{F_2-F_1}}$$

With this magnitude and position of $F_R$ the resultant has the same effect as the combined forces $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added the exact pages from the book in the question. Please let me know if the book is wrong or if I am misunderstanding it. Thanks

Comment: Also sorry if I am wrong but shouldn't it be $F_r\times x+F_2\times L=0$? (Because the forces act in the same direction.)

Comment: Here it should indeed be $F_r\times x+F_2\times L=0$ for the picture Gert chose. It is just a consistency issue however, he could have chosen to picture $F_R$ in the downwards direction instead. But you are absolutely right.

Comment: $F_r\times x+F_2\times L=0$ is incorrect. Because $F_2>F_1$, $F_R>0$  (pointing upwards, like $F_2$. The resultant torque about $O$ must therefore be anti-clockwise, like $F_2\times L$. Your formula would result in zero *net torque*, but that is not the case here. We're looking for the **resultant**, not a force that cancels out $F_1+F_2$.

Comment: Yes, it would seem I went a bit quick on this one, sorry.

Comment: @Gert: I am assuming my textbook is wrong in that case? Because it shows the blue vector acting outside the beam.

Comment: Not necessarily. I'd take Frotaur's explanation for it.

Answer (score 0):

As Gert stated, the resultant is **defined** as a single force on the system that has the same global effect as the forces **really** acting on the system. In this case, we have indeed that $F_R = F_2-F_1$ for the magnitude of the resultant and $x = \frac{F_2L}{F_2-F_1}$ the position from O the resultant should apply.

However, as you can see, it is possible to have $\frac{F_2}{F_2-F_1} =2$ (for $F_1/F_2 = 1/2$) in which case the resultant should act at $x = 2L$, which is **outside** your physical bar. There is however no problem because the resultant is a fictitious force which is useful for calculations, but do not reflect any physical reality.

So yes, it is possible that the resultant action be not on the object.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please also answer my second comment to Gert's answer?